# Setting up Tenda AC6 as a secondary router

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration, wireless-extender

I'm trying to set up a Tenda AC6 as a secondary router to extend Wifi signal, but can't work it out. I don't have any knowledge of networks, and I have looked for similar questions, but haven't found anything that can help me.

I have connected the Tenda to the primary router that is connected to the Fiber outlet (Sercomm FG824CD) through a LAN cable. Now I can connect to the Tenda, which seems to be mirroring the main router. The problem is that the Tenda's SSID does not have password, and I can't set it up. If I try to get into the Tenda admin page (via http://192.168.0.1), I only get the main router's admin page.

Is there any way to set up a password on the Tenda? (i.e. to access its admin page in this configuration) Or perhaps to set it all up in some way that it extends the original Wifi (even if it has a different SSID & password)?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do some stuff before connecting to the main Router

Power on your router and connect it via LAN to your PC

I'll tell you what i did in those cases:

If it's connected, you can now access to your Tenda Router config page (192.168.0.1)
Then you can config another IP to it, like 192.168.0.150 and make it static so it doesn't change when you connect it.

You can now connect both routers

If you type 192.168.0.1 you'll go to your main router
If you type 192.168.0.150 you'll go to Tenda router.

Hope it helps!
Regards,